# Libreoffice Base new record in Sub-Sub-Form

Tags: postgresql, libreoffice

I have a database structure of:

```
Contact
----
id serial
...

Note
----
id serial
note text

Contact_Note_Link
----
id serial
contact_id integer <- Foreign Key on Contact.id
note_id integer <- Foreign Key on Note.id
```

So, I have a Contact form with a sub-form of Contact_Note_Link, and a sub-form of that for Note. I can link notes to contacts easily enough, but how can I make a new Note, have it generate a new ID, link said ID to a new Contact_Note_Link which will be pre-filled by the Contact id via the Form->Subform relationship?